# Conditional Formatting two cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I want to have two cells that are filled light grey when both are empty. If one of the two cells have "XX" then neither cell are filled light grey.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Conditional formatting.

Comment: @ findwindow Did you come up with that on your own, or did you need the subject line to help you out that time? 8P~

Comment: @Jason, do a google search on "Excel Conditional Formatting" and see what you come up with.  If you are still having issues after completing that search and read, show us what you tried and we will be glad to help you...though I can promise to keep it less than or equal to 10 words!

Comment: I did hours of google search and didn't find what I was looking for.  That is why I created an account here to ask the question....

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

=AND(ISBLANK(D6),ISBLANK(D7),D7<>"XX", D6<>"XX")

But just the requirement that both be blank to be grey fills the requirement about xx which would be just =AND(ISBLANK(D6),ISBLANK(D7))

using the "Use a formula to determine which cells to Format" option in conditional formatting.